# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file of my HTML/PHP form

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
**</form>
    <table border = '1'>
        <tr>
        <?php date_default_timezone_set('America/Santiago');
        $vaFecha = date('d-m-y');
        ?>
        <td>Fecha</td>
        <td><input type = "text" name="caja_fecha" value = "<?php echo $vaFecha; ?>" disabled="disabled"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <form name="reloj24">  
        <input type="text" size="8" name="digitos" value=" " disabled="disabled">
    </form>  
    <script>
                $('#txtRut').Rut( {
            digito_verificador: '#Verificador',
            on_error: function(){ alert('Rut incorrecto'); 
            $("#txtRut").val("");
            $("#Verificador").val("");

        }
        } );
    </script>
</body>
```

**

I don't know where is the error, I need some help with this dilemma I have with my form.

Note: it's in spanish some words, sorry if u guys don't understand.

Comment: post your full code. Nobody can give an answer for this question to be honest with you, post the PHP code in full.

Comment: If you use a good IDE, it should help you find problems like this. It usually means you have unmatched brackets.

Comment: @Barmar just to ask which is a better IDE netbeans , eclipse or VS code?

Comment: I don't know them, I use PhpStorm.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for your input happy coding :)